# Send multiple ajax request parallel i want show file size progress bar

Tags: javascript

I am placed my code entries contains an array of my data all its send it to server. But the progress bar not working properly. I think progress not triggered.

```js
entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'base64upload',
        data: {'value':base64, 'filename': entry.filename, 'zipname':zipName[0], 'fileCount': fileCount,'image_title':entry.filename},
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#"+barid).css("width","100%");
            console.log("success="+barid);
        },
        progress: function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                $("#"+barid).css("width",parseInt( (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100), 10) + "%");
                console.log("progress="+barid);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make async: true and it will work